# Mypy error while calling functions dynamically

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Trying to type check this code (which works perfectly fine):

```
x = list(range(10))
for func in min, max, len:
    print(func(x))
```

results in the following error:

> main.py:3: error: Cannot call function of unknown type

How should this be handled?

Comment: casually, this might be an indicator _"the implementation is hard to explain"_

Answer (score 1):

You can try defining your sequence of functions before the loop. This runs fine with mypy:

```
from typing import Callable, Sequence

x = list(range(10))
funcs: Sequence[Callable] = min, max, len
for func in funcs:
    print(func(x))
```

Comment: `Callable` is `Callable[..., Any]`, i.e. untyped, so this is the same as using `Any` or `# type: ignore`

Comment: `Callable[[list[int]], int]` or `Callable[[list[int]], object]` is more precise

Answer (score 1):

If you know your argument to each of those functions will be of type `list[int]` and you know that each of them will return `int`, then you should specify that accordingly. You can define a [type alias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeAlias) to make this more readable:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterable
from typing import TypeAlias

ArgT: TypeAlias = list[int]
FuncT: TypeAlias = Callable[[ArgT], int]

functions: Iterable[FuncT] = min, max, len
x = list(range(10))
for func in functions:
    print(func(x))
```

If you are on Python `<3.10`, omit the `: TypeAlias`.